# Do Automated Workers build roads/railways?

Tags: civilization-5

When you automate a set of workers, they build improvements to land, but do they also build roads and or railroads?

Comment: Yes they do. Not really worth putting that as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, automated workers will also build roads, and when they become available, railroads.